# How to get the previous pushstate with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want something like `document.referrer`. But since I'm building a single page app, with `backbone` and `pushstate`, the value is `""`.

How can I get something like `history.prevState().url`.

**EDIT:** I do not need the event. I want to access info of the previous state anytime/anywhere I want.

Comment: when you change the view, you use history.pushState to push the url into history, and use the onStateChange event to respond to events

Comment: backbone router has handled all of that, so I do not want to insert a `onStateChange`. And more importantly, I do not need the event pattern. I want to access info of the previous state anytime I want.

Comment: @hbrlovehaku, Did you look at the updated answer?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could simply store the last state in the new state object.

```
history.pushState({
    lastState: 'some state'
}, '', 'newpage.html');

console.log(history.state.lastState); //some state
```

If you are building a single-page application, even if there are no standardization on how the state transition is initiated you could probably manage to intercept all of them by listening to the `popstate` and the `onhashchange` events.

You could then just push every states encountered in an array and store a serialized version of it in the `localStorage`. That would allow you retrieving any previous states. However, this collection will grow so you would have to make sure that you control it's size. You could also simply keep the last state instead of all of them.

However, it would definitely be better to establish a standard across modules. Not only it would make accessing the previous state easier, but it would also be easier to maintain and more flexible in terms of future changes.

Comment: What if this is out of control, e.g. the module for prev state is not written by me. Or by design patterns, we should know as less as possible about the prev module.

Comment: @hbrlovehaku Well, what will you do with the previous state object if you doesn't know anything about it? If you want to treat modules in a generic way, they must have some sort of common interface.

Comment: just want something like `document.referer`. even if I navigate from `http://A` to `http://B`, I know that info.

Comment: @hbrlovehaku, If you are not controlling state changes, you can still intercept them by listening to the `popstate` event. You could probably just push every states encountered in an array and store a serialized version of it in the `localStorage`. That would allow you retrieving any passed states. However, this collection will grow so you would have to make sure that you control it's size. You could also simply keep the last state instead of all of them.

Comment: I think you are right. We should have made a `navigate_wrapper` for the `Backbone.history.navigate` and stick to it all across the project. So we can save the states in this wrapper.

Comment: @hbrlovehaku Well I've never used Backbone yet, but if all modules were using `Backbone.history.navigate` it makes it quite easy to implement a mechanism for what you are trying to achieve if the library doesn't support it already. I updated my answer.